# How to Convert .p7b to .jks

Tags: ssl-certificate, jks, p7b

I have a certificate which is in **.p7b** I want change into **.jks**. So How can I convert it into **.jks**
please reply
thanks in advance

Comment: what have you researched so far?

Comment: thanks for quick reply I am seen some block but i failed to convert

Answer (score -2):

The alias should match the alias you used when you generated the key pair.
`keytool -importcert -alias alias -trustcacerts -file keystore.p7b -keystore newkeystore.jks –storetype JCEKS`

Source: [Import certs from a p7b to a jks](https://www.attachmate.com/documentation/gateway-1-1/gateway-admin-guide/data/fxg_keytool_importp7b.htm)